# Undefined Symbol when compiled with -O2 only on Mac

Tags: c, macos, linker

I'm working on a library that must compile on linux and mac os X. Until now, I had no problem, compiling with "-g" worked well under both OS.

I tried to compile with some optimization ("-O2") and it works well under linux but I get an Undefined Symbol when I try to link a program with my library under mac os X.

Does anyone have any clue what I should look for?

```
nm mylib.a | grep _the_symbol
```

This returns same thing for linux and mac (no leading underscore under linux) :

```
154:00000018 C _the_symbol
377:         U _the_symbol
```

Here is the compile line under linux for the program using the library:

```
/usr/bin/gcc  -std=c99   CMakeFiles/prod-cons.dir/prod-cons.c.o  -o prod-cons -rdynamic -L/home/claferri/dev/build/src ../src/libckaapi.a -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/claferri/dev/build/src
```

And under mac :

```
/usr/bin/gcc  -std=c99 -Wl,-search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -fPIC CMakeFiles/prod-cons.dir/prod-cons.c.o  -o prod-cons  -L/Volumes/Data/claferri/Work/build/src ../src/libckaapi.a /usr/lib/libpthread.dylib
```

Comment: Are you saying that nm for the Mac version, which gives the linker error, shows that the library contains the symbol?

Comment: Yes! I'm clueless about what's happening.

Comment: Does "_the_symbol" appear in your source code, and is it an uninitialized global variable? Is is referenced in your source code?

Comment: it appears in the library source code (but not in the program using the lib) and it is an uninitialized global variable.

Comment: @Neil : nevermind, the symbol appears also under linux (but without the leading underscore)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess at a workaround: try building the library with the -fno-common flag.  If you have multiple definitions of this variable, you'll need to add "extern" to all but one.

Comment: I had some variable defined multiple times and using -fno-common was very helpfull to see that (in fact not in my part of the code so not obvious) but the funny thing is that it wasn't the variable that was undefined at first ... Seems it now compile with extern definition of those other variables. Thank you!

Comment: in fact I still get the same error if I remove the -fno-common ...
I don't get why it works on linux and not on mac ...

Comment: My other thought was that it might be related to the order of the *.o files in the *.a archive.  Could you post output from "nm -A mylib.a | grep the_symbol"? Perhaps moving the object file containing the definition after the object file containing the reference will help the linker do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following is a guess, and I can't say for certain unless/until you provide the exact compiler flags you're using -- but Xcode defaults to setting `-fvisibility=hidden`, which would hide pretty much any symbol in your library, unless it's declared as visible.

You can do the same on Linux, but GCC's default is not to hide symbols.

You'll find more information here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: I don't use XCode to compile but CMake on both OS.